# AWS Xray setting up attempt:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I am attempting to add AWS X-ray tracing to my app, however, I have run into 2 problems.

- Firstly I am attempting to create this segment, however, I keep getting the error below  `Error: Failed to get the current sub/segment from the context.`. I found answers online here https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/tree/master/packages/core#context-missing-strategy-configuration, but am confused about where should I add this piece of code to make it work. `AWSXRay.setContextMissingStrategy("LOG_ERROR");`
- Also, I wanted to simply enable tracing for my lambdas, so I followed the steps and enabled it under configurations. However, when I go to the test tab and run the test, I do not see any instance of the run in the AWS X-ray. Is there anything else that is required?

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AWS XRay supports [2 tracing SDKs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-java-opentel-sdk.html): XRay SDK and ADOT(AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry)

Context missing is only happened in XRay sdk, to solve context missing user has to understand the XRay sdk implementation. It takes time so you can try to onboard ADOT, the new generation of SDK, to get rid of context missing problem.

ADOT in Lambda: https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda

ADOT java: https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/java-sdk